# How to pull to load more in Android?

Tags: java, android, animation

I'm using `SwiperefreshLayout` to refresh the data in my app. And to loadmore the data I have used [this library](https://github.com/shontauro/android-pulltorefresh-and-loadmore), but this library uses ProgressBar to show the process of loading data which I don't want. How to display the proccess loading the data such as `SwiperefreshLayout`, but is from the bottom up when I pull from the bottom up? I think can use `animation` to make loading button. I tried Google but could not found a way to be able to do like `SwiperefreshLayout`. Is there any suggestion for me? Thanks for help.